# how to put things in hashmap which is in another hashmap

Tags: hashmap, protected

i have something like this on top of my code:

```
protected HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Player>> prisonsPlayers = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Player>>();
```

And i need to insert data in it. As soon as i am new in java and never work with hashmap before its a bit problem. I try something like this but...

```
protected HashMap<String, Player> loggedPlayers = new HashMap<String, Player>();
prisonsPlayers.put(player.getName(), loggedPlayers);
```

Is it right or how can i do it other way?

Answer (score 0):

Yep you are doing right. It is called a `Mmulti Layered HashMap` behavior.

Add some values in `loggedPlayers` .

```
loggedPlayers.put(player.getName(), Player);
loggedPlayers.put(player.getName(), Player);
```

And add then

```
prisonsPlayers.put(player.getName(), loggedPlayers);
```